# Unsupported input type with ECW format geoserver

Tags: geoserver, gdal, ecw

Can anyone help me with an issue I am having with creating ECW datastores in Geoserver?
I have installed GDAL 1.9.2 and the latest plugin on Geoserver 2.11.2

When I put an ECW file in the /data_dir/data folder it can create the store and read the ECW.
You do have to use a relative path.
But when it is out of the folder (so anywhere on the server) or If you use an absolute path (ex: C:\geoserver\data_dir\data\theecw.ecw) I get an error.

This is the stacktrace I am getting:

```
2017-10-05 13:59:29,670 INFO [org.geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file://C:\theecw.ecw
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Unsupported input type
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:158)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItems(NewLayerPageProvider.java:61)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerDataProvider.fullSize(GeoServerDataProvider.java:243)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.updateMatched(GeoServerTablePanel.java:583)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:576)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:97)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$1.<init>(NewLayerPage.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.<init>(NewLayerPage.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreNewPage.onSuccessfulSave(CoverageStoreNewPage.java:86)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreNewPage.onSave(CoverageStoreNewPage.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.store.AbstractCoverageStorePage$1.onSubmit(AbstractCoverageStorePage.java:122)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:215)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1309)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:171)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:159)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported input type
    at org.geotools.coverageio.BaseGridCoverage2DReader.checkSource(BaseGridCoverage2DReader.java:320)
    at org.geotools.coverageio.BaseGridCoverage2DReader.<init>(BaseGridCoverage2DReader.java:162)
    at org.geotools.coverageio.gdal.BaseGDALGridCoverage2DReader.<init>(BaseGDALGridCoverage2DReader.java:84)
    at org.geotools.coverageio.gdal.ecw.ECWReader.<init>(ECWReader.java:68)
    at org.geotools.coverageio.gdal.ecw.ECWFormat.getReader(ECWFormat.java:93)
    at org.geotools.coverageio.gdal.ecw.ECWFormat.getReader(ECWFormat.java:45)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1511)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1441)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:95)
    ... 139 more
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Wild guess but have a try with forward slashes when you create the store `C:/geoserver/data_dir/data/theecw.ecw`

Comment: does your GDAL have the ECW format built in? are you on windows http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#adding-support-for-ecw-and-mrsid-on-windows ?

Comment: @user30184 ooh. I feel like an idiot :O it seems forwardslashes work. In an older version of the plugin backward slashes works as well.

Comment: @iant I am on windows. GDAL works if you use relative paths

Comment: do you have a server licence for ECW

Comment: Backward slashed should work, they are standard in Windows. I would call that as a bug. This question is not a duplicate even it does handle ECW but other answers do not deal with the bug in resolving the path on Windows.

Comment: @iant if the issue is with forward slashes, it's not actually a duplicate of that old answer, is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open GeoServer bug about bad File->URL conversion in file chooser 
https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8143

Until the bug is resolved you can use a workaround to write file paths with forward slashes also on Windows, like this:

```
C:/geoserver/data_dir/data/theecw.ecw)
```